# Power management Hardware, recommendation

Tags: battery, power, hardware

most real robots will need to provide different voltage level, i.e 5V for MCU, 12V for actuators, 19V for PC/NUC 24V for...
Also they all need to monitor charging of batteries as well as Overall power consumption.

I searched a while to find a ready product, or at least a DC DC converter with multiple output without success. I would prefer one PCB or DC DC converter for multiple outouts instead of multiple devices with single output.

I know this is not a specific question but it would help me a lot to understand, how others solve this.

BR Patrick

Comment: You would have more success by cross-posting this question over at Electronics StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

> I searched a while to find a ready product, or at least a DC DC converter with multiple output without success. I would prefer one PCB or DC DC converter for multiple outouts instead of multiple devices with single output.

I would strongly advocate for multiple DC-DC converters, each with a single adjustable output. This would simplify your debugging process, in case you ever need to do that. Moreover, if your PCB design skills are alright, you can also design your own power distribution board. Here you would benefit from using the same module multiple times, as you can copy over and replicate your design across let's say 5 times.

In case you decide to go this way, I'd like to remind you to not forget to filter your power supply at the output side as well, because the buck converters produce a lot of noise. You can look at ST1S41 and L6902 as reference